# Exception Message: Unable to connect to the remote server

Tags: sql-server, azure

```
I am trying to backup a database in azure storage and I keep getting the below messages
```

Msg 3271, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
A nonrecoverable I/O error occurred on file "azure storage backup file location" Backup to URL received an exception from the remote endpoint.
Exception Message: Unable to connect to the remote server.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Answer (score 0):

with so few details i can only suggest to look into the microsoft guide:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/admin/nonrecoverable-io-error-backup-url